# Lefschetz hyperplane theorem for etale homotopy groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory

**Lefschetz hyperplane theorem :** Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $H$ be a hyperplane section of $X$ such that $X \setminus H$ is a smooth affine(automatically true in this situation) algebraic variety, then the map $\pi_i(H(\mathbb{C})) \rightarrow \pi_i(X(\mathbb{C}))$ induced by the inclusion $H \hookrightarrow X$ on the homotopy group is an isomorphism for $i< \dim X - 1$ and is injective for $i = \dim X$.

Now, let us assume that $X$ is defined over a field $K$ of characteristic zero and $H$ as before. We can prove that $\pi^{et}_1(H) \rightarrow \pi^{et}_1(X)$ is an isomorphism if $\dim X \geq 3$ using weak Lefschetz theorem and the comparison theorem for topological fundamental group of $X(\mathbb{C})$ and etale fundamental group of $X$. Here we can use any embedding $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

It seems that that the isomorphism on etale fundamental group continues to hold in positive characteristic under certain assumptions ($H$ is also a regular hyperplane section.).

Let us now turn to etale version of Lefschetz hyperplane theorem conerning higher homotopy groups. I am new to this topic so I might be making several mistakes here. There do exist notions of higher etale homotopy groups which was first developed by Artin-Mazur. I have come to know that the first fundamental group computed in this theory does not match up with the Grothendieck's etale fundamental group but with the fundamental group defined in SGA3. There is an agreement when $X$ is a normal noetherian scheme. With this in mind, we may ask the following question :

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $K$ which can be of positive characteristic and let $H$ be moreover regular. Then what can we say about the induced map on higher etale homotopy groups? are they isomorphic in degrees up to $\dim X - 1$?

Comment: Daniel Litt has a paper on Non-Abelian Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorems. I don't recall if he gets into higher etale homotopy, but if nothing else he's probably the person to ask.

Comment: @TabesBridges I did look into the paper. I think higher homotopy groups are not dealt with in the paper but the paper is quite interesting. Thanks!